# Create download link for static asset file

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I would like to put a download link on my website so the users can download the file `template.csv`. The file is static and is located at the root of my `/grails-app/assets` folder.

Inside my `page.gsp`, I have tried 2 methods do so, to no avail :

- `<a href="assets/template.csv" download="template.csv">Download the template</a>`

  - this results in a `template.csv` file being downloaded, but the content is the html code of `page.gsp` rather than the original content of the file I uploaded in my assets.
- `<a href="${assetPath(src: "template.csv", absolute: true)}" download="template.csv">Download the template</a>`

  - the generated html file has a link to `localhost:8080/mysite/assets/template.csv` but clicking it prompts an error message : `Failed - no file`.

What is the correct way to do what I want to achieve ? Is there an issue with extra permissions I would need to add to allow the download of my file ?

Our webapp relies on a rather old technological stack :

- Grails 2.3.4
- Plugin asset-pipeline-2.2.5

Comment: add grails version and info about any asset prosessing plugins you are using

Comment: @TuomasValtonen I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had some troubles with downloading files straight with a -tag.

To overcome this, I use Controller method to return the file and place the downloadable files in their own folder under web-app/:

```
class MyController {

    @Autowired()
    AssetResourceLocator assetResourceLocator

    def downloadExcelTemplate () {

        String fileName = "MyExcelFile.xlsx"

        /* Note: these files are found in /web-app/downloadable directory */

        Resource resource = assetResourceLocator.findResourceForURI("/downloadable/$fileName")

        response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${resource.filename}"
        response.contentType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        response.outputStream << resource.inputStream.bytes
    }
}
```

And just use regular a-tag to to link to this controller method.
This way you also gain more control over file downloads.